# Subscript 1,1 at transponded matrix - what does that mean?

Tags: matrices, notation, transpose

I have to solve a specific equation, but stumbled about a notation I am not sure what it means. I already checked in the internet, but didn't find anything...
There's a transposed matrix with a subscript 1,1 in the right lower corner after the brackets. Please see the screenshot of the mentioned matrix, so that you know what I mean. What does that mean? Should I take the value of the 1st row and 1st column (x_ij = x_11) of the matrix? Would be great If you can help me!

All the other notations like T (transpose) and -1 (inverse) are clear.

[Screenshot of the Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpO5d.jpg)

Comment: $A_{i,j}$ is the $i$'th row, $j$'th column entry of the matrix $A$.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Notation).

Comment: To help reinforce that the first index is for the row and the second index is of the column, I make a pointed effort to only ever write the words row and column in that order.  You will never see me use the second term of "row and column" before the first.  Further, for applications, it is always RumRunners and CoastGuard, or Robbers and Cops (*despite the children's game usually be written in the other order*), or Robbie and Charles, etc...